# pegar o valor de campos inputs de um gridview com jquery

Tags: jquery, webforms

Preciso alterar os campos `inputs` de um `GridView`, e a medida que são alterados devo exibir a somatória desses campos `inputs` em um outro `input` que fica no rodapé da tela e a dúvida é: como pegar o valor desses campos inputs através do `JQuery`?

O **HTML** abaixo foi gerado pelo `GridView` e não sei como pegar o `ID` ou `NAME` do `input` uma vez que são criados **dinâmicamente**

```
<table id="gridModal">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Abril/2016</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>11,61</td>
        <td>
        <input id="gridModal_txtQtdNovo_0" type="text" value="11,61" name="gridModal$ctl02$txtQtdNovo">
        </td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Maio/2016</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>44,52</td>
        <td>
        <input id="gridModal_txtQtdNovo_1" type="text" value="44,52" name="gridModal$ctl03$txtQtdNovo">
        </td>
        <td>21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Junho/2016</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>42,58</td>
        <td>
        <input id="gridModal_txtQtdNovo_2" type="text" value="42,58" name="gridModal$ctl04$txtQtdNovo">
        </td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Julho/2016</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>40,65</td>
        <td>
        <input id="gridModal_txtQtdNovo_3" type="text" value="40,65" name="gridModal$ctl05$txtQtdNovo">
        </td>
        <td>19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Agosto/2016</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>44,52</td>
        <td>
        <input id="gridModal_txtQtdNovo_4" type="text" value="44,52" name="gridModal$ctl06$txtQtdNovo">
        </td>
        <td>21</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Esta foi a sugestão do `DanielDutra`, conforme a sugestão no comentário abaixo e atendeu minhas necessidades, porém a somatória só calcula a parte inteira desprezando a parte fracionada:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var _valor = 0;
        $("table#gridModal input").on('change', function () {
            _valor += parseFloat($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Você precisa pegar o valor de cada input separado? Se não basta obter todos eles com um `$('table#gridModal input')`.

Comment: sim separado, pois conforme eu altero o valor do input eu vou fazer a somatório com os demais

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como a outra resposta diz, o problema é realmente a vírgula nos números.

De acordo com [a resposta de outra pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571553/javascript-parse-float-is-ignoring-the-decimals-after-my-comma), o método `parseFloat` só considera a parte da string em que encontrar mais(+), menos(-), número, expoente ou ponto. Quando ela encontra qualquer outra coisa na string, inclusive a vírgula, ela desconsidera e faz o *parse* somente no que foi obtido no início.

Segue seu código alterado com a correção no `parseFloat`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var _valor = 0;
        $("table#gridModal input").on('change', function () {
            _valor += parseFloat($(this).val().replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Depois que a soma for feita, pode ser que você precise utilizar `replace('.', ',')` para exibir o valor final com a mesma formatação dos *inputs*.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo você precisa tratar os valores que vem dos inputs.

Para isso, segue a solução..

```
function numberFormat( num ) {
   var nFormat      =  num.replace(/\./g, '');
   nFormat  =  nFormat.replace(/\,/g, '.');
   return nFormat
}

var numero = "1.110,00";

alert( numberFormat( numero ) );
```

Pode conferir ela rodando [aqui JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aduque/61Lbf49m/)